# disabling the storage functionality of an usb stick and autostarting your program

Tags: c++, c, bash, shell, usb

is there a way to disable the storage functionality of an usb stick and autostarting
a specific program when plugging it it?
(so that the storage is all reserved for the program in question)

Comment: On Linux? Without any desktop environment or with a specific one?

Comment: Why intentionally cripple the capabilities of a USB drive to satisfy a seemingly arbitrary requirement? Why not let the user use the rest of the space e.g. to put other programs on it and/or save files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no way to do this without putting malware that cripples the host OS on the USB stick and relying on the host's OS to automatically run the malware the first time the device is inserted. This is of course frowned upon, both on Stack Overflow, and in general.